# Import huge nested XML files into Python and convert them to CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv, pandas

I have huge XML files with millions of rows consisting of hundreds nested attributes which I can't even extract properly and see what they are. I need to transform those XML files into CSV's in Python/Pandas and similar. Every suggestion here is based on solutions when you know already the names of your tags and which ones are nested which I don't in this case. I need to iterate through the files and create CSV's from them for each of the files and concatenate them into one CSV file. I am not sure about concatenation yet but probably I will need it. How can I approach this? I tried using xml.etree, dataframes and recursion but recursion dies on one file only and I have 20 even bigger files to go through.

Comment: how big are the files, actually? Big enough that a reasonable machine cannot load them or just your machine? (PS: don't let files get too large unless they can be properly stored/retrieved). Take a look at [this script](https://gist.github.com/benallard/8042835) and see if it can help you?

Comment: Just extract the first few lines of your huge files into new files (and work with those to develop your solution): you can do that from python, or from the shell - e.g. `head -5 huge_file.name > manageble_file.name`